# Why I got 404 error connecting two apps with flask

Tags: python, post, flask, python-requests

I'm Trying to connect two apps with flask:

```
  @app.route("/agent/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
  def agent():
  data = request.get_json(force = True)
  if(data):
           if(format(data['option']) == "1"):
              print(data['prepository']['run'])
              requests.post('http://some ip:4001/prepopsitory/', data['prepository'])
            return "hi" 
app.run(host = 'some ip', port = 4998)
```

and this one

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/prepository/', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def recibe():
     data = request.get_json(force = True)
     if(data):
          run = data['prepository']['run']
          prepository.formatea(run,1)
          return "hi"  
app.run(host = 'some ip', port = 4001)
```

The thing is when i send a Postman to Agent app it doesn't works, it shows a 404 on the second app (prepository)

when i run line by line in

```
   @app.route('/prepository/', methods = ["GET","POST"])
```

says

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

I don't know if the two problems are related or not.

**EDIT**

Now I've tried anything that pops into my head, i discovered that if i send the post directly to prepository it does work. 
Given that i assume is a problem with the connection between the two apps.
Also I've changed the library used for the get and post, it was `flask.request.get_json`
now is `requests.post` or `requests.get`
still doesn't work.

Comment: just off top of my head, what happens if you remove the last slash from the urls? so instead of ```/prepository/``` you put ```/prepository```

Comment: the same **10.40.3.147 - - [13/Mar/2019 12:17:10] "POST /prepopsitory HTTP/1.1" 404 -**

Comment: did you try specifying the port when sending requests with postman?

Comment: my postman url is http://10.40.3.xxx:4998/agent/, the **prepository** runs on 4001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this is suppose to work, it looks like both your `prepository` and `agent` routes have been configured to handle `GET` and `POST` requests, but your routes **don't distinguish between incoming GET and POST requests**. By default if you don't specify the supported methods on your route, flask will **default to supporting a GET request**. However, with no check on the incoming request your routes don't know how to handle the incoming requests, since both `GET` and `POST` are supported. A simple conditional like the following: `if flask.request.method == 'POST':` can be used to distinguish between the two types of requests. Maybe you could add the above mentioned conditional check, to check for each type of request so your application services can respond appropriately. Something along the lines of:

```
  @app.route('/agent', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
  def agent():
      if request.method == "GET":
          msg = "GET Request from agent route"
          return jsonify({"msg":msg})
      else: 
        # Handle POST Request
        data = request.get_json()
        if data:
            # handle data as appropriate

        msg = "POST Request from agent route handled"
        return jsonify({"msg": msg})

app.run(host = 'some ip', port = 4998)
```

For debugging purposes just send a very simple `json` response back to verify configuration correctness as it's hard to tell if your data object is set up appropriately as is. Then once both of your services are verified as working, you can start building out your application services to communicate with one another.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Working solution. Thanks!

Comment: np glad I was able to help!